# Square POS API adding Unique ID, is it possible?

Tags: javascript, android, square-connect, square

I am working with Square POS API and have successfully sent a request to the android app via a mobile web app. The app opens, displays the correct price, accepts payment and returns to the callback URL.

I have read over the documentation a few times and may be missing it but is there a way I can add a Unique ID that is sent to the app and returned to the callback page  so I can update the correct line item in the database?

possibly something like:

*"l.com.squareup.pos.UNIQUE_ID=" + unique_id + ";" +*

```js
  var posUrl =
    "intent:#Intent;" +
    "action=com.squareup.pos.action.CHARGE;" +
    "package=com.squareup;" +
    "S.com.squareup.pos.WEB_CALLBACK_URI=" + callbackUrl + ";" +
    "S.com.squareup.pos.CLIENT_ID=" + applicationId + ";" +
    "S.com.squareup.pos.API_VERSION=" + sdkVersion + ";" +
    "i.com.squareup.pos.TOTAL_AMOUNT=" + transactionTotal + ";" +
    "S.com.squareup.pos.CURRENCY_CODE=" + currencyCode + ";" +
    "S.com.squareup.pos.TENDER_TYPES=" + tenderTypes + ";" +
 "l.com.squareup.pos.AUTO_RETURN_TIMEOUT_MS=" + callbacktime + ";" +
 "l.com.squareup.pos.UNIQUE_ID=" + unique_id + ";" +
    "end";
```

Comment: I was able to add a Unique ID to the "S.com.squareup.pos.NOTE=" + note + ";" + line but I am unable to access it from the callback url

Comment: The `note` field is a good place to put this, and in order to retrieve it you would need to call `RetrieveTransasction` on the `transaction_id` that is returned to your application.

Comment: Can the callback URI have parameters wired in by you when you provide it to square?